# What is the $project (aggregation) API for Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm rather new to MongoDB, I can find some commands in shell to execute my query, however, I can not find a proper function in PyMongo API manual.

For example, I would like to project some of the fields of the document to a new document. I suppose the $project could do it, but there is no such support in Pymongo. How could I execute the same query both in shell and Python? For example:

```
db.books.aggregate( [ { $project : { title : 1 , author : 1 } } ] )
```

Comment: What makes you say there is no such support in Pymongo? Can you show us the queries you have tried to run that have not given you the desired result?

Comment: @chridam please see above, how to code it in Pymongo? thanks.

Comment: @arunk I do not think so. It is an example on the official manual. see here [link] (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) _italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: can you give a sample document in your collection

Answer (score 2):

For projecting you may use the query as

```
db.books.aggregate([{'$project':{ 'title':'$title', 'author':'$author'}}])
```